# Identify Error in the below code

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm getting error in the below code at line var f1.dob =  new Date(), what may 
be the reason for the error.
Also not getting output for table.

Below is the Java script code:

```
var app=angular.module("demofilter",[]);
console.log("Inside app.js");
app.controller("filtr",[function(){
    var fl = this;
    var f1.dob = new Date();
    console.log("date",f1.dob);
    fl.employees = [
        {"name":"Vishwa","age":27,"Desig":"Sr.UI Dev"},
        {"name":"Raju","age":30,"Desig":"Manager"},
        {"name":"Ramu","age":34,"Desig":"Sr. mgr"},
        {"name":"shyam","age":22,"Desig":"Trainee"}
    ];
}]);
```

below is the  HTML code:

```
<body>
<div ng-controller="filtr as fl">

<h4> Date Filter</h4>
 <p> {{fl.dob}}</p>

<table>
    <thead>
        <th>sl No.</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Age</th>
        <th>Desig</th>
    </thead>
   <tr ng-repeat="emp in fl.employees track by $index"></tr>
   <td>{{$index+1}}</td>
   <td>{{emp.name}}</td>
   <td>{{emp.age}}</td>
   <td>{{emp.desig}}</td>


</table>

</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="libs/angular.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is `f1` defined? What error are you getting? You're setting `var fl = this;` right above it, if you meant to set `var f1 = this;` and you're getting an undefined error that's it.

Comment: What is the error you are getting? What is the specific problem?

Comment: Error is:   Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token .
angular.js:68 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module demofilter due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'demofilter' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument

Answer (score 3):

This is syntactically incorrect:

```
var f1.dob = new Date();
```

A `var` declaration is for declaring variables, not object properties. I *think* you probably wanted to add a "dob" property to the "fl" (not "f1") variable created in the line before that:

```
var fl = this;
fl.dob = new Date();
```

Comment: `var fl.dob` is also a syntax error. **You do not need `var` there.**

Comment: That is right, What is the error you find in table?

Comment: I don't see any errors with the `fl.employees` array. That looks fine.

Answer (score 2):

I would try changing the dob line to something like this:

```
var fl = this;
fl.dob = new Date();
```

This could be done more succinctly.

Also, do you really mean to define `f1` and `fl` variables?

Comment: @vishwa you're not really helping much by just commenting something vague like, "not working".  *How* doesn't it work? Errors? Undesirable behavior? People cannot read your mind.

Comment: I have edited to reflect that it should be `fl` rather than `f1`